# Python cProfile results do not appear to add up

Tags: python, arcpy, cprofile

I have attached a screenshot of the cProfile results of a Python script.  I know the second line refers to a geoprocessing function in the arcpy site-package.  However, I am unclear what the first line refers to:

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing_base.py:498()

I see line 1 was called 3 times at 72s per call and line two was called once for 216s per call.  However, these do not appear to add up to 219s.  How should I interpret these results?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to differentiate cumulative time from function time. The numbers on the left correspond to time actually consumed in *this* function. Cumulative includes both time consumed in this function, plus time consumed in all subfunctions.

So, in this case, `FeatureClassToFeatureClass` called a lambda function 3 times, but otherwise did very little. The lambda itself took ~72s per call, for 3 calls, for a total of ~216s. It didn't call anybody else, so its cumulative time is roughly equal to its cum time. The `FeatureClassToFeatureClass` function did not do much itself, so its total time is nearly zero. However, since it called the lambda function 3 times, and that function was long-running, its cumulative time is high.